# mysql commands difference and example

Tags: mysql, function, procedures

I'm new in mysql language and can not understand difference between procedures and functions, can anyone answer in which case should be use this routines ?

---

Also have some example => I've table named "data" and columns named "id"(primary key) , "local". this local includes multiple exactly same data. I want to search every id of this "data" (and after result manipulate with it) table which local equal to (for instance) 'something'

Please answer in this question ... Thanks

Comment: select id from data where local='something'

Answer (score 0):

Functions:

```
 select <function>(column) from table where <condition>;
```

Procedure:

```
 call <procedure>( param0, param1 );
```

To get your result:

```
 select * from <table> where data like "%something%";
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you use php with mysql.

your query should be

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE local='something'");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
     // here you manipulate with your data
     // for example:
     echo $row['id'];
}
```